# Django: Only update fields that have been changed in UpdateView

Tags: django, django-forms, django-class-based-views

I'm using an UpdateView to update a series of fields. However, I only want fields that have been modified to be saved to the database. If a value was not provided for a field during update process, I want the previous value to be used as the default. If a new value was provided for a field then only that field should be updated. How do I go about accomplishing this?

```
#views.py
class AccountUpdate(UpdateView):
""" Updates an account; unchanged fields will not be updated."""
context_object_name = 'account'
form_class = UpdateForm
template_name = 'accounts/update_account.html'
success_url = '/accounts/home'

def get_object(self, queryset=None):
    return self.request.user

def form_valid(self, form):
    clean = form.cleaned_data
    #encrypt plain password
    form.instance.password = hash_password(clean['password'])
    context = {}
    self.object = context.update(clean, force_update=False)
    return super(AccountUpdate, self).form_valid(form)

#templates
{% extends 'base.html' %}
<title>{% block title %}Update Account{% endblock %}</title>
{% block content %}
{{ account.non_field_errors }}
<div class="errors" style="list-style-type: none;">
    {% if account.first_name.errors %}{{ account.first_name.errors }}{% endif %}
    {% if account.last_name.errors %}{{ account.last_name.errors }}{% endif %}
    {% if account.email.errors %}{{ account.email.errors }}{% endif %}
    {% if account.password.errors %}{{ account.password.errors }}{% endif %}
    {% if account.username.errors %}{{ account.username.errors }}{% endif %}
</div>
<form action="" name="edit" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <ul>
        <li>Fullname</li>
       <li> {{ form.first_name }}{{ form.last_name }}</li>
        <li>Email</li>
        <li>{{ form.email }}</li>
        <li>Password</li>
        <li>{{ form.password }}</li>
        <li>Username</li>
        <li>{{ form.username }}</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li><input type="submit" value="update account"></li>
    </ul>
</form>
<ul>
    <li class="nav"><a href="/accounts/">cancel changes</a></li>
</ul>
{% endblock %}
```

All the fields are also declared as required in `models.py`. Currently the form only works if i provide a value for each field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> i'm using a custom hash during update process to encrypt passwords. When i visit the edit page and hit update button, the old password in its current encrypted form gets re-encrypted hence losing the old password

I would handle that by not including `password` itself in the form.  Instead, I would add a new field (something like `new_password`) to allow entering a new password.  Then, in your `is_valid` method, set the password to the hashed value of that field if there's content.

You should also use the [sensitive value filtering](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/error-reporting/#sensitive_variables) tools to prevent user passwords from showing up in emailed error reports.

```
class UpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = user
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'username')
    new_password = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.widgets.PasswordInput)
```

And then in your view:

```
@sensitive_variables('new_password')
@sensitive_post_parameters('new_password')
def form_valid(self, form):
    clean = form.cleaned_data
    new_password = clean.get('new_password')
    if new_password:
        #encrypt plain password
        form.instance.password = hash_password(new_password)
    return super(AccountUpdate, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. Based on your comment on Rob's answer, I think I'll be able to solve the individual field update problem. I'll post my solution once complete. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not quite sure what other field update problem you're having - it should be harmless to set, say, `first_name = "Joe"` if it's unchanged.

Comment: If the update_form is pre-populated with `first_name = 'joe'` but the user decides to delete the value in that field on the update page and leave it blank, i want `first_name` to default back to `joe`. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I see.  That's something that's harder to set up using the generic views, at least if you're still allowing for the possibility of some of the fields legitimately being blank.  I guess you could loop through the form's `changed_data` names, see if they're blank, and if so copy in the `self.object` version's values.

Comment: `if you're still allowing for the possibility of some of the fields legitimately being blank.` All four fields are required. Can I still go ahead with the loop?

Comment: If all four are required (and they're not by default on the Django user model) the simplest thing to do is to mark the fields as required at the form level.  To do that, either define the fields yourself (somewhat annoying) or change their `required` attribute in a custom `__init__` method - the latter's a common shortcut for when you want to change only a little bit about the default form fields from a model.

Comment: The fields are already defined as required in my models.py and inherited in forms.py like so: `first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=Account._meta.get_field('first_name').max_length,                                 error_messages=Account._meta.get_field('first_name').error_messages,)`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to pre-populate the fields with what's already there.
Do this on the template with `{{ account.name }}` or whatever.

Comment: I've updated the the question with my template file. when i go to the edit page the form is already pre-populated with values except for  password field(not sure why) but when i attempt to save the form nothing happens unless i fill out all blank fields

Comment: Try `render_value=True` on `password`. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.PasswordInput

Comment: Ok, the render_value=True worked...only issue is, i'm using a custom hash during update process to encrypt passwords. When i visit the edit page and hit update button, the old password in its current encrypted form gets re-encrypted hence losing the old password. On another note, since the form is already being pre-populated how do i go about solving my initial issue of only updating changed fields?

Comment: The only way i can think of is using a series of if-elif statements to match each field in the db with submitted values to see if they're different and then perform individual field update queries...this sounds tedious and un-pythonic

Comment: It should be harmless except for the password situation, but if you do need to go that route, note that forms have a 'changed_data' attribute that will contain the names of the fields that changed.

Comment: I would only do that check for the password field, that would avoid your double hash issue. As for the others, what's the problem if they get updated, provided the values are correct?

Comment: Also, why are you showing a password on the update form? Put that on a separate form, or allow it to be empty if the user isn't changing his/her password.

Comment: `As for the others, what's the problem if they get updated, provided the values are correct?` None at all; but, if a field is left blank the form will not update.