# How can I combine two views and two forms into one single template?

Tags: python, django

I have two separate class-based views and would like to keep their functionality, and have the two CBVs point to the same template (I'm trying to bring two separate forms into a single page).

More specifically, I am trying to subclass/combine [this email view](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/account/views.py#L372), and this [password change view](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/account/views.py#L534), so that I can have them point to the same template, as I ultimately would like both forms on the same page.

I've attempted to do this by subclassing them into my own views:

```
class MyEmailUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, EmailView):
    template_name = 'account/account_settings'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('settings')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        return super(SettingsUpdateView, self).form_valid(form)

class MyPasswordUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, PasswordChangeView):
    template_name = 'account/account_settings'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('settings')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        return super(SettingsUpdateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

But I am now finding out due to errors, one by one, that it appears nothing from the parent class is actually transferred over to my custom class unless I manually bring it in(success_url, methods, etc). Even then, the code from the original classes that I am subclassing is pointing elsewhere.
SO, when combining these two views, do I need to copy all of the original code into my custom subclass views?

Is this the proper way to accomplish it? How can I combine these two views? I'm ultimately looking for a way to have both of their forms on a single page in my own app. Is there possibly a simpler way to accomplish this using the [library's provided templates](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/tree/master/allauth/templates/account)?

Comment: When you say "I ultimately would like both forms on the same page," do you mean you want one single URL to point to a page with both forms?

Comment: @ubadub a single url to a page w both forms, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think You can use the default class in django to a achieve the same result.
As far as i understood i got the scenario like this we have two django forms and we need it to be used in same template if that is the scenario we can use the LoginView from `django.contrib.auth.views` which has several customizable option like you can give the additional form like this

```
class LoginUserView(LoginView):
    authentication_form = LoginForm
    extra_context = {"register_form": RegistrationForm}
    template_name = 'accounts/index.html'
```

it will be using the get context data method to update the form which you will be able to get in the template and use accordingly .If you are not wishing to use the code like this you can still use it like this

```
class MyEmailUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, EmailView):
    form_class = EmailForm
    template_name = 'account/account_settings'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('settings')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MyEmailUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['password_reset_form']  = ResetPasswordForm
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        return super(MyEmailUpdateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Then you can handle your post in the form valid accordingly as your requirement.
Hope that helps get back if you need any additional requirement.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Django Multi Form View](https://github.com/TimBest/django-multi-form-view) to combine many forms in view

After install you can use it like below:

```
class MultiFView(MultiFormView):
    form_classes = {
        'email_form' : AddEmailForm,
        'change_password_form' : ChangePasswordForm
    }
    record_id = None
    template_name = 'web/multi.html'

    def forms_valid(self, forms):
        email = forms['email_form'].save(commit=False)
        email.save()
        return super(MultiFView, self).forms_valid(forms)
```

and in template:

```
{{ forms.email_form.as_p }}
{{ forms.change_password_form.as_p }}
```

Comment: I would rather a method that does not rely on another third party library

Comment: ...lol..like the Dutch saying: "what the farmer does not know
he does not eat".. as Simon said ;-)

Comment: Simon just try this library. why are you trying to reinvent the bicycle?

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved by implementing a (kind of) partial update method for your view.

**Tools:**

*First protect your sensitive data:*

1. [`sensitive_variables`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/error-reporting/#django.views.decorators.debug.sensitive_variables) decorator:

   > If a function (either a view or any regular callback) in your code uses local variables susceptible to contain sensitive information, you may prevent the values of those variables from being included in error reports using the sensitive_variables decorator
2. [`sensitive_post_parameters()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/error-reporting/#django.views.decorators.debug.sensitive_post_parameters) decorator:

   > If one of your views receives an HttpRequest object with POST parameters susceptible to contain sensitive information, you may prevent the values of those parameters from being included in the error reports using the sensitive_post_parameters decorator

*Create some code after:*

3. Use [`ModelForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform) to create a form with specific fields of interest for your view. Don't include the `password` field, because we will add it in a different way to suit our needs:

   `myapp/forms.py`:

   ```
   class PartialUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
       new_password = forms.CharField(
           required=False, widget=forms.widgets.PasswordInput
       )

       class Meta:
           model = MyUser
           fields = ('email', 'other_fields',...)
   ```

   *Here you can use `exclude` instead of `fields` if you want to keep every other field except the `password`: ex. `exclude = ('password',)`*
4. Use an [`UpdateView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#updateview) to handle the hustle and override it's `form_valid` method to handle the partial update:

   `myapp/views.py`:

   ```
   class MyUpdateView(UpdateView):
       template_name = 'account/account_settings'
       form_class = PartialUpdateForm
       success_url = reverse_lazy('settings')

       @sensitive_variables('new_password')
       @sensitive_post_parameters('new_password')
       def form_valid(self, form):
           clean = form.cleaned_data
           new_password = clean.get('new_password')
           if new_password:
               form.instance.password = hash_password(new_password)
           return super().form_valid(form)
   ```
5. Finally, create a url for that view:

   `myapp/urls.py`:

   ```
   ...
   url(r'^your/pattern/$', MyUpdateView.as_view()),
   ```

This way you can handle:

- Email AND password update at the same time
- Only email update.
- Only password update.

---

Using code from this solution: [Django: Only update fields that have been changed in UpdateView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18343361/django-only-update-fields-that-have-been-changed-in-updateview?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: Seems a whole lot of nothing-really-related-to-my-question.

Comment: @simonsays It allows you to have a single view for handling email or password update (or both at the same time), which you can then add to a single url. But if you think so...